# Avoid copies of an object to call the destructor

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a small rendering engine for 2d graphics and I want to keep it as simple as possible, especially trying to avoid the usage of (smart) pointers and heap allocations.

The problem is now, that I am creating a VertexBuffer object in renderer.init() and pass this via a copy to VertexArray::setVertexBuffer(VertexBuffer).
As soon as the program leaves the scope of VertexArray::setVertexBuffer(VertexBuffer), the destructor of the copied object is called and deletes the underlying opengl vertex buffer.
Eventually, this leads to an access violation as soon as the next opengl command, involving the vertex buffer, is called.

Obviously, if I turn VertexArray::vertexBuffer_ into a shared_ptr, this behavior is gone because the underlying object is only deleted when the ref-count of the shared pointer goes to 0.

I am just curious if there is any way to avoid the constructor being called on that copied object and therefore doesn't delete the underlying opengl vertex buffer.

I simplified the code a bit, to make the example as compact as possible.
Your advice is much appreciated.

Here is the code to visualize the problem:

```
class VertexBuffer
{
  ...
  uint32_t vertexBufferId_;
  ~VertexBuffer()
  {
    glDeleteBuffer(1, &vertexBufferId_);
  }
};

class VertexArray
{
  ...
  VertexBuffer vertexBuffer_;
  setVertexBuffer(VertexBuffer vertexBuffer)
  {
    vertexBuffer_ = vertexBuffer;
    //when the program leaves this scope, vertexBuffer.~VertexBuffer() is called
    //and the underlying opengl vertex buffer gets deleted
  }
};

class Renderer
{
  ...      
  Renderer Renderer() : vertexArray_{};      
  VertexArray vertexArray_;
  
  renderer.init()
  {
    VertexBuffer vertexBuffer{};
    vertexArray.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
  }
}

main(...)
{
  Renderer renderer{};
  renderer.init();
}
```

Comment: It’s a bit unclear what you actually need to do and what your constraints are. That said, you should consider passing a reference instead of a copy. And you should almost certainly remove your `setVertexBuffer` function and pass the vertex buffer reference inside a constructor instead.

Comment: In terms of the code, there are no constraints since this is only a hobby project. If i turn the copy into a reference, won't it call the destructor as soon as i leave renderer.init()

Comment: Short answer: no there isn't. C++ does not work this way. A constructor is always called to construct an object, and a destructor is always called when it gets destroyed. This is fundamental and axiomatic to C++. In certain situations one can play games with placement new/destroy, etc, but that takes advanced skill and C++ experience to do correctly without breaking anything.

Comment: Why not send by reference?

Comment: "I am just curious if there is any way to avoid the constructor being called on that copied object". NO! If it is a copy, it needs to be destructed. Full stop! If you do not want a copy, use a ref or a pointer. Quite curious to understand what is the "real problem" You should give us more background and think yourself about the design flaw you have. Until any needed change for your question I would close it!

Comment: I'd use *move* semantics to pass-by-move the VertexBuffer to VertexArray.  Pass-by-value will make a copy.  Pass-by-reference will only exist as long as the aliased object exists, which may be okay in your scenario (but tends to be a little more brittle as projects grow larger).

Comment: "Pass-by-reference will only exist as long as the aliased object exists" is what i wasnt sure about. Thank you Eljay

Comment: In this scenario I strongly recommend marking the copy constructor/copy assignment operator of `VertexBuffer` as deleted. This will result in a compiler error, if you accidantally use a copy constructor: `VertexBuffer(const VertexBuffer&) = delete; VertexBuffer& operator=(const VertexBuffer&) = delete;` Move constructors/assignment operators could be an option, but this is even more advanced than the topics you mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor of a class determines what it owns. Ownership scope is the main determining factor of class functionality. The language doesn't allow destructors to be skipped because it would defeat the intended conceptual model.

It looks like `VertexBuffer` is an "owner" class and `VertexArray` is an "observer" class. Then, `VertexArray` should not contain a complete `VertexBuffer` object, but instead it should have a `VertexBuffer&` reference or a `VertexBuffer*` pointer.

The job of `shared_ptr` is to count references and release a shared object automatically. If you are already managing the `VertexBuffer`, then you don't need that. Other smart pointers likewise solve ownership problems. You can apply a smart pointer wherever you manage heap memory. However, avoidance of smart pointers will not improve the implementation of your chosen memory management strategy.